# Unexpected critical dependency on LDAP

Tags: systemd, dns, ldap, ntp

I'm using LDAP for user authentication **only** (nsswitch.conf below) on Ubuntu 18.04. However if the host cannot connect to the LDAP server at boot time, startup is blocked by NTP and DNS.

The LDAP integration is implemented by ldap-auth-client (not sssd).

```
A start job is running for Network Name Resolution
A start job is running for Network Time Synchronization
```

Removing the LDAP entries from nsswitch.conf allows the system to boot.

Can I remove the dependency and still allow the host to boot up?

nsswitch.conf:

```
passwd:         compat systemd ldap
group:          compat systemd ldap
shadow:         compat ldap
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Comment: Can you clarify which dependency you are asking about?  When you say "dependency", are you talking about software package dependencies?  E.g. are you asking if the ldap-auth-client package can be removed?  Do you want LDAP functionality to work after the dependency is removed?

Comment: I want to be able to authenticate with LDAP. I want my host to boot up when the LDAP server is not available.

Comment: Do you have either "nss_initgroups_minimum_uid" or "nss_initgroups_ignoreusers", in /etc/ldap.conf?  If yes, is it possible to see the values?

Comment: No, neither set.

Answer (score 1):

During normal operation and during normal boot up, there can be lots of user id (uid), group id (gid) and group membership verifications being performed.  If you have LDAP configured for user/group lookups, then this can become a problem if there are issues communicating with the LDAP server.  Even boot up tasks which deal with system accounts (e.g. ntp, root) can cause LDAP lookups to happen.  There is a way to tell your client system to avoid some LDAP lookups for certain accounts (e.g. system accounts), where it's unlikely that LDAP is providing any benefit / information anyways.

My best guess is that you can fix the boot up delay / block by adding a "nss_initgroups_ignoreusers" entry to your /etc/ldap.conf file.

Example entry in /etc/ldap.conf:

```
nss_initgroups_ignoreusers ntp
```

However, I don't know why an entry with "nss_initgroups_ignoreusers" is not already there.  Since you have Ubuntu 18.04 with ldap-auth-client, I would have expected libnss-ldap (which is a dependency of ldap-auth-client) to be installed, and with libnss-ldap you get /etc/init.d/libnss-ldap, which calls nssldap-update-ignoreusers.   nssldap-update-ignoreusers will create an entry for nss_initgroups_ignoreusers.

Instead of editing ldap.conf directly, you can try running (as root or with sudo) nssldap-update-ignoreusers manually (in fact this might be better than the example above where only "ntp" is used, since it will create a more complete list of users to ignore for LDAP group lookups):

```
 nssldap-update-ignoreusers
```

You might want to save a copy of your ldap.conf file before doing any of this, although nssldap-update-ignoreusers does save a diff file somewhere.